# Why is reader.ReadToEndAsync() timing out? The code use to work and now it times out

Tags: c#

I'm trying  to figure out why the this `webResponse = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();` is timing out.

```cs
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
{
    webResponse = response.StatusDescription;
}
else
{
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        webResponse = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be using `HttpClient`. `WebRequest` is legacy, and for good reason.

Comment: @Andy i understand why you would say that however you did not take into context that i might be stuck using  WebReques because of legacy software or limitations that are out of my control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I had to do was go back to the calling method and change it to async and then await the call that has this code in it and remove the .Result that was creating the deadlock.